# Can you be suffocated from being smothered by a pillow?

Tags: mortality, suffocation

We've all seen it in movies. A villian suffocates one of his/her victims with a pillow while they sleep, killing them in a matter if a minute or so.

Whenever I've pushed my head into a pillow as far as it will go, I can still breathe. I even asked one of my friends to pretend to smother me (very realistically) and I could still breathe through the pillow.

Is this form of suffocation a myth?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Belgium there is a well known and documented case (I think it even included video footage) of an asylum seeker which died this way during her expulsion, so I guess there is at least some truth to it. Definitely also depend on other factors as the type of pillow and the force applied.
Read about the case here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semira_Adamu

Answer (score 15):

Yes,

[Source 1](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-452275/Mother-arrested-boy-smothered-death.html):

> A young mother has been arrested after her four-year-old son was
>   suffocated to death with a pillow in a domestic tragedy

[Source 2](http://www.floridacapitalcases.state.fl.us/case_updates/Htm/755994.htm):

> Reeves died as a result of asphyxia from being smothered with a
>   pillow.